# Formatting Dates in ranged-based dropdown list

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula

I've created a dropdown based upon a range of list of dates (List from range). I've formatted the cell in question that has the date displayed, so that it only displays Month/Year (i.e. November 2019). However, when the dropdown is selected, it displays the dates in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, which is a little harder to scan through.

Does anyone have any idea on whether there's a way to change the format of the date displayed in the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

select your list of dates and convert it to **Plain text**:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p5vS.png[2]]

---

then you will have:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEHSY.png[1]]

Comment: Great idea, thanks for this. However, unfortunately, I think this will likely impact the formulas elsewhere, as I need it in date format as part of the overall functionality.